# Check if a collection contains an object, comparing by reference

Tags: java, collections

The [Collection.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method check if a collection contains a given object, using the `.equals()` method to perform the comparison.

From Java7 Javadoc:

> **boolean contains(Object o)**
>
> Returns true if this collection contains
>   the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this
>   collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ?
>   e==null : o.equals(e)).

Is there a smart way to check if a collection contains an object `o`, but comparing by reference instead (i.e. `o==e`)?

Of course I can iterate through the collection and make the check, I'm looking for an existing function which can do that.

**Clarifications:**

- I want to perform this operation *regardless* the `equals()` implementation of the object in the collection.
- I don't want to change the objects in the collection nor the collection itself.

**Edit:**

Even though my question is about a general solution for `Collection` implementations, specific cases for `Collection` sub-interfaces would also be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if a solution using the [exists method from apache commons collections utilities](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) could work? Define a Predicate that is an instance check for the object you're trying to find.

Comment: "The Collection.contains() method check if a collection contains a given object, using the .equals() method to perform the comparison" <-- the documentation is rather misleading here; this is not true for all collection types. For instance, `Sorted*` collections rely on natural ordering. And `IdentityHashMap` relies on... Reference equality (!) for keys.

Comment: @Paolo In this case you need to override equals() and hashCode() to achieve your requirement. Also suggested in one of answers below.

Comment: Can you post something which you have tried?

Comment: @Exu do you mean code which shows the problem or code which tries to solve the issue? First one, I think it is not needed. Last one, see [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22560840/323447)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For those of us using Java 8, [`Collection#stream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) is a clean option:

```
collection.stream().anyMatch(x -> x == key)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is some kind of workaround...

You can use an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), with `Void` as values (or whatever else -- your choice). You'd then use `contains()` on its `.keySet()` to check the presence of an element (or `.containsKey()` on the map directly).

A second workaround would be to use Guava and [`Equivalence.identity()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#identity%28%29); however your `Collection` will have to have elements of type `Equivalence.Wrapper<X>` and you'd have to `wrap` before checking...

---

Curiously enough, the JDK does not provide an `IdentityHashSet`. This is rather strange considering that the internal implementation of `HashSet` uses a `HashMap`, so one has to wonder why they didn't do the same for `IdentityHashMap`...

---

Side note: the documentation of `Collection` is misleading; *not all `Collection` implementations rely on `.equals()`*. See, for instance, `SortedSet` or `SortedMap`. And, of course, `IdentityHashMap`.

Comment: There's [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)) if you need an IdentityHashSet.

Comment: @user2357112 uh, I had forgotten about that one! Probably because I have never used it ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to check that the way you are trying to do. Without iterating through collection you cannot check that the object  point to same reference or not.

AFAIK, No (*At least a clean way*).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a class you should override at least `equals` (and `hashCode`) methods.
If you implement your `equals` method to compare by reference you will achieve your goal.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: I want to perform that operation regardless the `equals` implementation. Added as clarification in my question.

Comment: @fge The OP wanted to check if Collection contains a given object by reference. Why would overriding object's `equals` method to compare references not be an answer?

Comment: In that case you will have to implement your own Collection

Comment: Because OP said explicitly that this should work regardless of the class' `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` implementations... And the JDK does have a collection implementation of it (sorta) with `IdentityHashMap`

Comment: @fge This was a later clarification by OP if you care to read the post and comments... The answer was a solution for original question.

Comment: No. The original question clearly asked "[...]Is there a smart way to check if a collection contains an object o, but comparing by reference instead (i.e. o==e)?". It is only because of all answers mentioning `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` that the OP felt obliged to edit for clarification.

Comment: @fge Overriding `equals` method to compare references would handle the requirement automatically because Collection (Map is **not** a strict Collection unless you will consider it as a Collection of Entry elements in which case it follows the same patten) will have to check object `equals` to decide if the entry is present.

Comment: Not all `Collection`s rely on `.equals()`!! See `TreeSet`, which implements `Collection`... Also, why would you want to override `.equals()` since `Object`'s one does identity comparison?

Comment: @fge Who guaranteed that the object you will be storing extends `Object` directly and not another class with possible alternative implementation of `equals`
As for TreeSet it uses HashMap to enforce `unique` clause of the Set

Comment: You still don't get it, do you? Here what is wanted is _reference equality_. And this is where `IdentityHashMap` comes in. As for `TreeSet` it DOES NOT use `.equals()` to enforce uniqueness. Try and insert `new BigDecimal("1.0")` and `BigDecimal.ONE` into a `TreeSet`: those two are not `.equals()`, but the resulting set only contains ONE element. This is because their `.compareTo()` returns 0.

Comment: Yes, I don't get it: how does overriding `... equals(Object o) { return this == o; }` not produce the desired outcome?

Comment: Because the OP wants it to work _regardless of the class' implementation of it_ (ie, without having to override it at all)

Comment: @fge - as far as I understand it TreeSet implementation is in breach of contract between `equals()` and `compareTo()`

Comment: Which is why I said that the documentation of `Collection` is misleading... The `SortedSet` interface "violates" `Collection`'s definition of `.contains()`, not `TreeSet` alone (`TreeMap` also behaves this way)

Comment: @fge - as I mentioned earlier OP clarified that they did not want class dependent implementation later.

Comment: @fge - Tree alrrady implies the sorting, and once again Map is not a stict Collection

Comment: A `Map`, no; its `.keySet()`, yes ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answers point out that it is not possible *in a clean way* to perform the desired check.

So this is a possible implementation of such requested function:

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the collection contains the specified element.
 * <p>
 * More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this collection
 * contains at least one element {@code x} such that {@code x == element}.
 * <p>
 * Note: {@link Collection#contains(Object)} works differently because uses
 * {@link Object#equals(Object)} for comparison
 * 
 * @param collection
 *            collection where to look for the element
 * @param element
 *            element whose presence in this collection is to be tested
 * @return {@code true} if this collection contains the specified element
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if {@code collection} is null
 */
public static <T> boolean containsReferenceTo(Collection<T> collection,
        T element) {
    if (collection == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("collection cannot be null");

    for (T x : collection) {
        if (x == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**NOTE:**
this may be optimized for some specific `Collection` implementations.

Comment: Note: with Java 7 the null check can be written `Objects.requireNonNull(collection, "collection cannot be null");`

Comment: can anyone optimize the function in case `collection` is an instance of `IdentityHashMap`?

Comment: Well, it won't be an instance of `IdentityHashMap` since `Map` does not implement `Collection`... It is its `.keySet()` which does; and I don't believe there is a way to detect that

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by wrapping the object in your own object which implements the `equals` you are looking for.

Something like:

```
private class Identical<T> {
    final T held;

    Identical (T hold) {
        held = hold;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object it) {
        return it != null && held == it;
    }
}
```

Obviously you would have to take control of adding items to the collection and wrap each one in one of these.

You could wrap the map like this:

```
static class ReferenceHashMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, Identical<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static class Identical<T> {

        final T held;

        Identical(T hold) {
            held = hold;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object it) {
            return it != null && held == it;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return held.hashCode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        Identical<V> value = map.get(key);
        return value == null ? null : value.held;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Identical<V> replaced = map.put(key, new Identical<>(value));
        return replaced == null ? null : replaced.held;
    }

    private class MyEntry implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

        private final K key;
        private V value;

        public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            V old = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            return old;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Entry<K, V>> entries = new HashSet<>();
        for (Entry<K, Identical<V>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            entries.add(new MyEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().held));
        }
        return entries;
    }

}
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to replace the keys with `Identical<K>`, instead of the values? also, in your first block of code, the `hashCode()` method is missing.