# How to convert beans with bi-directional reference?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I wrote some generic bean conversion that used together to convert a complex bean. Sometimes the input bean has bi-directional reference, and the converter traps in an infinite loop. How can I manage that?

For example the input is A bean that has relation to B bean and B bean has relation to exactly the A instance. When converting the A object starts, the B converter invokes to convert the b field in A, and also on converting the B object, A converter invokes to convert the a field in the B class, and as you know, the converter traps on infinite loop. Think about a more complex relation between beans that the relation graph has more than two nodes.

How can I avoid this infinite recursion in the converters?

Comment: Use an `IdentityHashMap` to keep a reference to the objects already transformed, and check in the `IdentityHashMap` before transforming a new object if it's not already in it.

Comment: @fardjad `IdentityHashMap` doesn't use `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Object references form a **net**.

```
A -------> B
^--- C <---'
```

When serializing to XML, JSON or similar, you are building a **tree**. Since a tree is a simpler form of a net you can not simply copy one into the other.

```
A
'--> B
     '--> C
          '--> A (recursion alarm!)
               '--> ...
```

A common solution is to

- either stop serializing, as soon as recursion is detected (just keep track of all objects that are already serialized)

  ```
  A
  '--> B
       '--> C
  ```
- or, when detecting recursion, add a stub reference to another node in the serialized tree. A unique identifier of nodes is required.

  ```
  A(1)
  '--> B(2)
       '--> C(3)
            '--> Stub that links to (1)
  ```

For the technical detail of storing the already serialized objects:

- using a `HashSet` might seem handy as it does not contain duplicates - but since it requires `hashCode` and `equals` methods for all items this is generally **not a good idea**
- using the keys in `IdentityHashMap` can be used, it will compare keys using `==` and not contain duplicates
- but since you usually check if the collection already contains the item before to add it, you can also use `ArrayList` with this code: [`collection.stream().anyMatch(x -> x == key)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567482/476791)