# Comparing two collections using Stream - anyMatch

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to compare if any of the objects in a `list2` is present in a `list1`.

I could iterate over both lists and compare all elements using `.contains()` but I am wondering if there is not a more efficient way. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557042/check-if-a-collection-contains-an-object-comparing-by-reference) and I am trying to implement the suggested method:

```
List<Item> list1;
List<Item> list2;

boolean anyMatch = list1.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.equals(list2.stream()));
System.out.println(anyMatch);
```

When I do this I constantly get `false`, even when I'd expect a `true`. How come?

Comment: Steams have a lot of scaffolding to keep state for lazy evaluation.

Comment: You are comparing an element in list1 with the stream of list2. They are not even of the same type. You won't make anything faster with streams. you could use list1.equals(list2) but order will matter. Use Set instead of List if order doesn't matter and items are unique.

Comment: @Tunaki Should have been list, my bad. 
I want to compare if any of the objects in list2 is present in list1. 
Should have been clearer.

Comment: How would you do this with iteration? Show an example so we can more clearly understand.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From your comments, you have two lists, `list1` and `list2`. You want to find out if at least one of the element in `list2` is contained in `list1`.

With the Stream API, you can acquire a `Stream` of `list2`. Then, a call [`anyMatch(predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) returns whether one of the element of this stream matches the given predicate, which, in this case, tests whether the element is contained in `list1`.

```
boolean anyMatch = list2.stream().anyMatch(list1::contains);
```

This uses a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as the predicate.

You would have better performance by converting the `list1` into a `Set`, which guarantees constant-time look-up:

```
boolean anyMatch = list2.stream().anyMatch(new HashSet<>(list1)::contains);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Although [@Tunaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36670693/1876620) is correct, here's another more concise way (it doesn't use `Stream.anyMatch()` method, though):

```
boolean anyMatch = !Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);
```

This uses the [`Collections.disjoint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) method, which returns `true` when two collections have no elements in common.

Tunaki's comment regarding performance also applies here: for better performance, the best would be to turn your `list1` into a `HashSet`, because its `contains()` method is `O(1)` average. The `Collections.disjoint()` method actually checks if any of its arguments is a `Set` and iterates over the collection that is not a `Set`. So in your case, all you have to do is create a `HashSet` from your `list1`:

```
boolean anyMatch = !Collections.disjoint(new HashSet<>(list1), list2);
```

Note: After all, my answer is only 5 characters shorter that Tunaki's :)

Comment: Thanks for showing another way for achieving this. I take it that both methods have an equal performance if I convert a list into a `HashSet`?

Comment: @k88 They have equal performance if the stream is sequential. If it's parallel, it will perform better when lists have many elements (a couple thousands or more, you would have to test it, depends on the machine). Also, for best performace, you should convert the list which has more elements to a `HashSet` and iterate over the other one.

Answer (score 9):

- Using Java 8 stream api

```
boolean isAnyMatch = list2.stream().anyMatch(list1::contains);
```

- Using Collection class method

```
boolean isAnyMatch = !Collections.disjoint(new HashSet(list1), list2);
```

Anyway converting list to set before comparing will give faster output.